# How to retrieve current date and time in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix

I need to store date in one variable and time in variable. Are there any methods to get date and time in solidity?

Answer (score 2):

there is a datetime library you can find out more here
https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.